# create hierarchical view tree type

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

From the table below, I need hierarchical view of fNAME, lNAME, USER_MAIL and PARENT_USERNAME, the path follows by lNAME/PARENT_USERNAME

```
create table USER (
USERNAME varchar2 (30),
fNAME varchar2 (30) not null,
lNAME varchar2 (30) not null,
USER_PHONE char(10) null,
USER_MAIL varchar2 (30) null,
PARENT_USERNAME varchar2 (30) null,
constraint USERNAME_PK primary key (USERNAME) );
```

Comment: Include sample data along with the results you're expecting with the question

Comment: Ok, I did it :) thx, I though to mention only SQL :)